# How get two elements with attr

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/dude_jsfiddle/CQ9qm/

```
  <ul>
    <li class="jstree-leaf" kids="0" range="5-7" name="mars" public_id="mars_05" ra_depth="5">
    </li>
    <li class="jstree-leaf" kids="0" range="8-10" name="pluto" public_id="pluto_8" ra_depth="5"
    </li>
  </ul>

alert($(document).find("li[name='pluto','mars']").length);
```

who knows how to get the two elements?

pluto and mars in one find

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).find("li[name='pluto'],li[name='mars']").length
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alert($(document).find("li[name='pluto'],li[name='mars']").length);
```